# Jetty: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not valid encoding

Tags: java, jetty

With embedded Jetty (`9.4.5.v20170502`), using a servlet handler, and with URL:

```
http://localhost:8081/?para=%u65E5
```

(this URL is sent by Chrome as traffic is sniffed to another production server).

I need to have a test case for this scenario using Jetty.

There is an error:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Unable to parse URI query
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameters(Request.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameterNames(Request.java:1036)
    at MyServlet.service(MyServlet.java:15)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
```

which originates from:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not valid encoding '%u6'
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeHexByte(UrlEncoded.java:889)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeUtf8To(UrlEncoded.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeUtf8To(UrlEncoded.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpURI.decodeQueryTo(HttpURI.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractQueryParameters(Request.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameters(Request.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameterNames(Request.java:1036)
    at MyServlet.service(MyServlet.java:15)
```

However, when using [HelloWorld Handler](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/embedding-jetty.html), there is no error for the same URL when calling `request.getParameterNames()`.

Main class:

```
public class JettyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Server server = new Server(8081);

        // doesn't work
        server.setHandler(getServletHandler());

        // works
        // server.setHandler(new HelloHandler());
        server.start();
    }

    private static Handler getServletHandler() throws IOException {
        final WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
        context.setContextPath("/");
        context.setResourceBase(".");

        final String pathSpec = "/*";
        final Class<? extends Servlet> servlet = MyServlet.class;
        context.addServlet(servlet, pathSpec);

        final WebAppClassLoader loader = new WebAppClassLoader(context);
        context.setClassLoader(loader);
        return context;
    }
}
```

MyServlet:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void service(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        for (final Enumeration<String> paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
                paramNames.hasMoreElements();) {
            final String name = paramNames.nextElement();
            final String[] values = request.getParameterValues(name);
            for (final String value : values) {
                System.out.println(name + " " + value);
            }
        }
        response.getWriter().write("something");
    }
}
```

HelloHandler:

```
public class HelloHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    final String greeting;
    final String body;

    public HelloHandler() {
        this("Hello World");
    }

    public HelloHandler(String greeting) {
        this(greeting, null);
    }

    public HelloHandler(String greeting, String body) {
        this.greeting = greeting;
        this.body = body;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

        for (Enumeration<String> en = request.getParameterNames(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            System.out.println("name " + en.nextElement());
        }
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<h1>" + greeting + "</h1>");
        if (body != null) {
            out.println(body);
        }

        baseRequest.setHandled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your url is not property encoded. Try this url `http://localhost:8081/?para=%25u65E5`

Comment: The parameter value is sent as is by Chrome, and another production server doesn't complain.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in Jetty. A user can craft a URL that causes Jetty to fail to handle the request.

On Jetty 9.4.15, I've found it to be as simple as appending ?%%0 to a URL. As soon as the code handling the URL tries to access the query parameters, Jetty throws an exception:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Unable to parse URI query
```

For now, I'd say there is not a good solution or work-around.

It could be that this only happens when a malicious person is testing your site for weaknesses. In this case, it is probably acceptable that Jetty stops processing, rather than continuing with bad data.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: I just use 'encodeURI(url)' in javascript in my browser application (before the ajax function) and the problem was solved